# JavaScript Mystery: form & fieldset, input element refer

Tags: javascript, forms, fieldset

It is a real mystery on javascript when we try to refer all elements on an from with fieldset.

The code works pretty well when we do use an array to hold value.

But When we only and directly alert of the value, nothing works.

Check this out, it is simple:

http://jsbin.com/lecodo/1/edit

```
function read(my){
  var values= []; 
  e=my.elements; 
  for(i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    values.push(e[i].value); //It works, you can see when you submit the form
    //-Now convert it above to note and than make the code below works:
    //alert(e[i].value); //It doenst work, you can try it on page load

    //bug solution that I discovered: e=my.elements; to e=my[0].elements;
    //This solution will cause a lot of incompatibilty 
                               }
    my.onsubmit = function() {
    alert(values);return false; }
}
window.onload=function(){read(document.forms[0]);}
```

HTML form code:

```
<form action="post.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Fale conosco!</legend>
<label>Nome: <input value="Colodetti" name="nome" type="text"/></label>
</fieldset>
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Please help this out. It happens at last on Google Chorme and IE.
I need to use the fieldset inside the form. So we can solve it? any suggestions please

How we do report that error to an JavaScript reference??